# how to remove a sub directory in qt5

Tags: c++, qt5

I have a complete directory like this,

C:\server\videos\images

and this images folder may contain several images. I want to delete this images folder if there are images available in it. so how can I do that in qt5.

I've seen some of the question similar like to this.but they aren't seem to solve my problem.
I don't want to delete my entire directory or an image file.I just need to delete the image folder if there are images on it.So how can I do this?

thanx in advance.!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Removing a non empty folder in Qt](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11050977/removing-a-non-empty-folder-in-qt)

Answer (score 1):

Check if the directory is empty or not (contains images or not):
[Check if directory is empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16351699/check-if-directory-is-empty)

Then, you can remove it + its content:
[Removing a non empty folder in Qt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11050977/removing-a-non-empty-folder-in-qt)

Or only its content files:
[Delete all files in a directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14754977/delete-all-files-in-a-directory)

Comment: but isn't it delete the directory also?

Comment: You're right, deleting files but not the folder can be achieved as proposed by John Doe

Answer (score 0):

If you do it like jpo38 suggested then just create that folder again after deleting.
Or you just try to delete each file in the folder like mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14754977/delete-all-files-in-a-directory).